# Significato di "muina"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Ma per la prima volta in vita sua, insieme a quella sensazione lo aveva preso un pensiero, una specie di presentimento, che comunque fossero andate le cose, avesse anche evitato le trappole del malocchio, i sortilegi, l’invidia, le guerre e le malattie infettive, prima o poi sarebbe morto, e non c’era modo di sfuggire al fatto che quel suo corpaccione che sembrava tagliato nell’olivo sarebbe diventato molliccio e si sarebbe sfatto come i torsoli delle pannocchie e gli altri residui che buttavano nelle pozze per concimare la terra. La **muina** in basso mescolandosi a quei pensieri gli faceva girare la testa.

Per situare il contesto di questo brano, cito un passaggio precedente:

> Ma la notte della vigilia di San Giovanni un caldo prematuro e soffocante aveva fatto cuocere il sangue nelle vene di don Francesco. Arrivavano fino a loro, attutite, le canzoni che cantavano per strada.

Quindi, tutto questo accadeva durante la notte della vigilia della festa di San Giovanni. Don Francesco era nella sua camera da letto e aveva i pensieri descritti nel primo passo citato. Immagino che questa "muina" sia qualcosa correlata ai festeggiamenti che si stavano facendo per strada, "in basso" (perché la stanza dove si trovava don Francesco non era al piano terra).

Non ho trovato il termine "muina" su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino si tratti di qualche sorta di regionalismo o dialettalismo. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: C'entrerà forse con questo? http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ammuina

Comment: Ha perfettamente senso, @DaG.

Comment: Come “la matriciana”. Era diffuso nelle nostre campagne il solecismo “aradio” (Ho sentito per aradio) da “la radio” che veniva presa per “l'aradio”.

Comment: @egreg: Anche in castigliano ho sentito "arradio" per "radio" o "amoto" per "moto" (cioè, motocicletta).

Comment: Ci sono parole italiane che sono nate per una separazione “scorretta” tra articolo e nome, ad esempio «bottega», che deriva da «apotheca» - l'apoteca - la bottega (con normali fenomeni p/b e c/g). È il bello delle lingue, che prima sono parlate e poi scritte :-)

Comment: @Benedetta:    Credo sia il fenomeno che accade con gli esempi dallo spagnolo che ho fatto prima. Si tratta di parole che finiscono in *-o*, quindi qualcuno pensa che siano maschili (in realtà sono femminili) e che si dica "un amoto" o "un arradio" invece di "una moto" o "una radio".

Comment: Se ammuina c'entra, questa pagine vale una lettura: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facite_ammuina

Comment: Sì, i fatti narrati hanno luogo a Grottole, nella Basilicata, che faceva parte del Regno delle Due Sicilie. All'inizio del romanzo si è nel 1861, poi il tempo avanza e si arriva fino al XX secolo.

Comment: @DaG: Ricercando su Google "ammuina muina" ho visto che appare [qui](http://sites.unice.fr/site/henneboi/SVG-lirces/langues/real/dialectes/ammiscare.htm) come "muìna", da Piccitto II, cioè, dal volume II del *Vocabolario siciliano* di Giorgio Piccitto.

Comment: Poi ho trovato questo [Dizionario dialettale 
etimologico di Mormanno](http://www.ferdinandopaternostro.it/luigi/pdf/dizionario.pdf) che riporta "muìna" col significato di "confusione 
chiassosa".

Comment: La cosa curiosa è che sembra trattarsi di un "cognate" del verbo catalano "amoïnar", che significa "preoccupare", "annoiare", "infastidire".

Answer (score 3):

Comincio col dire che, senza il commento di @DaG, non sarei stata in grado di trovare questa risposta.

Come ipotizzato nel commento di @DaG, a quanto pare, il termine "muìna" è una variante di "ammuìna".

Questo [dizionario etimologico di meridionalismi dell'Università di Nizza](http://sites.unice.fr/site/henneboi/SVG-lirces/langues/real/dialectes/ammiscare.htm) indica che "muìna" è riportato sul volume II del *Vocabolario siciliano* di Giorgio Piccitto col significato di

> sentore di rabbia popolare che tende a esplodere

L'autore di questo vocabolario ([Arnaldo Moroldo](http://www.ald-monaco.org/membres)), però, mette in correlazione questo vocabolo con "ammoìno" o "ammuìno", riportati sul volume I del *Vocabolario siciliano* di Giorgio Piccitto con queste accezioni:

> confusione, disordine; trambusto, baraonda; chiasso, frastuono, pandemonio 2 baruffa, tafferuglio 3 festicciola piuttosto animata 4 ammutinamento, cfr. *ammuina* e *ammuinari* 2.

E, per "*ammuinari* 2", dà:

> ammutinarsi...3 affollarsi, far ressa...

Questa fonte registra altre varianti del termine riportate da Gerhard Rohlfs nel *Nuovo Dizionario dialettale della Calabria*.

Anche questo [Dizionario dialettale 
etimologico di Mormanno](http://www.ferdinandopaternostro.it/luigi/pdf/dizionario.pdf) riporta "muìna" col significato di

> confusione chiassosa.

Il vocabolo "ammuìna" o "ammoìna" è registrato da parecchi dizionari della lingua italiana, come il Treccani, lo Zingarelli, il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, il Garzanti e il Battisti-Alessio (secondo quanto si spiega [qui](http://sites.unice.fr/site/henneboi/SVG-lirces/langues/real/dialectes/ammiscare.htm)). Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ammuina), per esempio, viene definito come

> Vocìo, chiasso, fracasso, confusione: *fare ammuina*

e altri vocabolari riportano definizioni simili.

Nel contesto del testo citato nella domanda, possiamo concludere che "muina" significa qualcosa come vocìo, trambusto, baraonda, chiasso... prodotti da una festicciola popolare "piuttosto animata", con l'aggiunta di una sfumatura di confusione causata da una folla.

Un'altra possibile interpretazione, secondo la definizione di "muìna" del Piccitto, sarebbe che si trattase della sensazione di una certa esplosione di un senso di rabbia popolare. Tuttavia, dato l'ambiente festivo descritto nel testo, che continua parlando di risate, di bagliori di fiamme (dai falò tipici della notte di San Giovanni), di braci e di occhi di ragazze che brillavano nell’ombra, di "cafoni festanti", questa interpretazione mi sembra poco plausibile.

Comment: @egreg: Grazie mille della tua correzione: avevo scritto "ammüìna" perché è così come appare sul Treccani. Ma veramente non sono sicura se sia meglio lasciarlo nella forma "ammüìna" oppure "ammuìna". Immagino non abbia molta importanza.

Comment: Le dieresi sono molto poco usate in italiano; solo in poesia per spezzare un dittongo in iato. E si scrive sulla seconda vocale, non sulla prima. È possibile che in napoletano sia pronunciato come iato, ma direi che la pronuncia normale in altre parti d'Italia sarebbe con il dittongo (ammesso che venga indovinata la tonica).

Comment: @egreg: Sì, immagino fosse soltanto un'indicazione di pronuncia da parte del Treccani.